# Постраничная загрузка pdf

Tags: pdf, android, java

Возможно ли загружать и отображать pdf файл по частям?
Например, если файл большой, а памяти мало (на мобильнике), то скачать например только первых несколько страниц, остальные подгружать по мере необходимости.
Существуют ли java библиотеки с таким функционалом?
Если нет, какие библиотеки (желательно free) для отображения pdf на android  посоветуете?

Comment: а как вы его загружаете сейчас, не постранично?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно проблема PDF загрузки документа связана с загрузкой ресурсов, например шрифтов, которых может быть помимо стандартных адобовских стотыщмиллионов. Ну и уж совсем для эксперимента попробуй открыть большой (> 2х страниц) документ в блокноте. Ну нету там страниц. Есть трейлеры, стримы, объекты, строки. Соответственно пока по всему документу дерево объектов не построишь - нет у тебя страниц. А если совсем не повезло, и вместо нормальной PDF разметки все страницы это гигантские высокого разрешения картинки напиханые в ресурсы, сдохнет процессинг PDF на мобиле. Поэтому как решение - клиентский сервис, обменялся с серваком документами, он ему ПДФ, а обратно весь документ в картинках, или хочешь 10ая картинка, хочешь 1593я картинка странички. Сам пишу под Xamarin.Android. Если актуально, могу поделиться ссылкой на библиотеки для рендеринга PDF. Но гугл найдёт больше.